# What is the frame field for in ifconfig?

Tags: 14.04, networking

Specifically, what does it mean if I have a line like this in a networking interface?

```
Rx packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:142
```

I'm pretty sure Rx means the packets being received from the device, but I'm wondering what it means if only the frame field increments.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/309867

Comment: @Pilot6 I saw that one, but it said frame errors. Is that field indicating frame errors or number of frames?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows number of frame errors.

When connection is good, it always shows 0.

Frame errors mean CRC failures on receipt of a frame. The root cause of this could be a bad cable, or a bad interface on either the machine or the switch. Try replacing the cable, then moving to another port on the switch.